Kotlin getter method has not been called
I have ported a pretty big project to Android system from c# to Kotlin.
I now face a strange bug that sometimes methods and parts of business logic are not executed. When debugged I got a green message that says "method has not been called".  What! Is this a mutiny!? I have never seen a program refuse to execute a line of code and then continue onward as if nothing has happened, no exceptions no log messages.
My setup
internal class SaleValidator(sharedService: SharedService) : BaseValidatorPart(sharedService) {
  private val fiscalReceipt: FiscalReceipt get() = SS.printerState.currentReceipt!!.fiscalReceipt!!;

  override fun execute(args: Any) {
    // ..
   fiscalReceipt.addTurnover(context.sumWDiscount, context.vatId);
   fiscalReceipt.updateTax(context.vatId, SS.printerState.taxes[context.vatId]);

  }
}

The turnover never gets added, and when i try to step in addTurnover method I get this green message  at the bottom of android studio "method getFiscalReceipt() has not been called". If I put the property to the "Evaluate Expression" input I can can confirm that the object exists and is accessible.

This property is there to shorten the access to the object, and it is guaranteed that the object exists when this method is executed and the getter is accessed.
There is no async or suspend functions involved, everything is regular functions
The validator method executed is invoked in a try catch block

What do I miss? Do I need to comb my entire project and replace my getters? In cases like this would expect an exception thrown or in the worst case crash the application. But never continue as if nothing has happened.


https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-5086/Smart-step-into-skips-method-call-and-shows-false-message-Method-has-not-been-called-if-the-overridden-method-was-actually

this does sound like my problem, upon further investigation i realized that the message has mislead me as the real problem was that my ported method wasn't adding.. Do i delete this question now?

Never delete a question/answer if you think it might be useful for others. Clearly in this case you weren't aware of the existing issue and I'm sure there will be others so it's nice they can find it here. I'd suggest adding your own answer and marking it as answered.

Turns out the getter was actually called, but the IDE message mislead me due to a bug described in the kotlin but tracker.
I thought to believe the message was correct because of my own bug in addTurnover function that did nothing instead of adding the turnover.
